# Character group and tate module of algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field and $\bar k$ a separable closure. For an algebraic $k$-torus, denote by $G_* = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{G}_{m, \bar k}, G_{\bar k})$ its group of cocharacters. This is a finitely generated, free abelian group with a continuous $\mathrm{Gal}_k = \mathrm{Gal}(\bar k , k)$ action.  Then it is claimed at various places that there exists a natural isomorphism of $\mathrm{Gal}_{k}$-modules
$$
G_* \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(1) \cong T_\ell(G)
$$
where $T_\ell(G)$ denotes the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $G$, i.e.
$$
T_\ell(G) = \varprojlim_{n} G[\ell^n](\bar k)
$$
Here $G[\ell^n](\bar k)$ denotes $\bar k$-valued $\ell^n$-torsion points of $G$.

Since $G_*$ is a flat and finitely-presented $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it suffices to show
$$
G_* \otimes \mu_{\ell^n} \cong G[\ell^n](\bar k)
$$
I am unable to find a proof of this nor did I find a reference. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an isomorphism
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb G_{m,\overline k},G_{\overline k})\otimes \mu_{\ell^n}&\simeq G[\ell^n](\overline k)\\
\varphi\otimes z&\mapsto \varphi(z).
\end{align*}$$